# Keep track of links clicked via Javascript cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have three pages on my website.

- When a button is clicked on the first page it directs the user to the second.
- When at the second page the user has the choice whether to choose to
  add the 'addon' to their order or skip it.
- Whether they add or skip the 'addon', they then move onto another page which offers the same thing but a different 'addon'

Through these two pages I want to keep track of whether the user has clicked add or skipped the addon to know which payment link to finally send them. On the first page if the 'add' addon button is clicked I create a JavaScript cookie as shown below:

```
onclick="createCookie("addon1", "yes", 0)"
```

On the second page I do the same thing but create a cookie for addon two:

```
onclick="createCookie("addon2", "yes", 0)"
```

With the JavaScript being

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
 }
```

If I have created both these cookies, how can I process them at the end of the three page cycle to know what cookie(s) exist(s) and therefore which payment link to redirect to?

As on the second page as the cookie is being created I also somehow need to it be read and understood whether it exists. It's confusing me. Do I need an extra page to process whether these exist?

Answer (score 1):

If the second prompt redirects you, you'll need to have another page.

To read cookies, you can use ***Zeus.js***'s built-in `zeus.getCookie()` function.
`zeus.getCookie()` works like this:

- All Cookies are smooshed into a single string, `document.cookie`
- `zeus.getCookie()` picks out the desired key from the string
- A string is returned.

---

For example, if you set a cookie, `document.cookie = "like=trains"`, you can use `zeus.getCookie("like")` to return the value, `trains` (as a string).

---

To use ***Zeus.js***, simply put

**`<script src="https://rawgithub.com/thetakeaway/zeus.js/master/zeus.js"></script>`**

in `<head></head>`.

Cheers!

Comment: So why doesn't this work if the `addon2` cookie exists and the value is `yes` `if (zeus.getCookie("addon2") == "yes")`

Comment: There is no error just nothing happens, this is my HTML link for you `<a href="#" onclick="createCookie("addon2", "yes", 0)">` within the `createCookie` method i create the addon2 cookie and then see if addon2 cookie exists using the code above. Is this right?

Comment: Ahh.  There is a quotation mark error.  Try `<a href="#" onclick="createCookie('addon2', 'yes', 0)">` @Luke14

Comment: No problem! Let me know if there are any other things you would like that have to do with cookies or arrays, as I'd be more than happy to include them in **Zeus.js**! @Luke14 ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50082/discussion-between-jczimm-and-luke14)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of the cookies, you can split the cookies of a site by exploding `document.cookie` by the `;`, and explode the parts of that by `=` to get an array of cookies set:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';'); 
var cookieObject = {}; 
for(var i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){
    var c = cookies[i].split('=')
    cookieObject[c[0]]=c[1];
}
```

You can run this before the moment you actually want to see if cookies have been set and check if `cookieObject` contains `addon1` or `addon2`.

If it's just the *existence* if the cookie you want, you can simple make a search function for document.cookie like:

```
function doesCookieExist(cookie) {
    return document.cookie.search(cookie) >= 0;
}
```

This returns true or false. You can make it more robust by combining the two functions above. Convert to array, then search the array.

Comment: After the final add button is pressed I am looking for the existance of the cookie named 'addon2' but its not working even though I am calling it from the onclick even of the link.          `var myCookie = getCookie("addon2");

    if (myCookie == null) {
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
    else {
        window.location.replace("http://google.com");`  
    }

Comment: so.. what does getCookie do?

Comment: Can you show me your `getCookie()` function? Or is it @Jorg 's?

Comment: it does nothing, how can I do a simple search to see if it just exists i dont care about the value as its only going to exist if the user has clicked on the button anyway